# Clone dynamic content by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which shows result of a quotation form. Results changes if user change form value instantly. I want to display or copy the same results of that div to another div or more like a "second version" of that div.I know this below sort of code will work.

```
$("div1").clone().appendTo("div2");
```

But it works only for the 1st time page loads. After that it doesn't change the results with the div1 results.

Does anyone have a hint on what to do here?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want it to change when the user changes it? Sounds like you need to add an event listener and call the code....

Answer (score 0):

Use the onchange event in your html on the form. Then call your code from it somewhat like:

```
onchange="$('div1').clone().appendTo('div2');"
```

or

```
onchange="someJSfuncion();"
```

also dont forget to delete the old copy. Further information:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your event handlers on form changes and then copy the output to other div. Example:

```js
// Original js
(function() {
  $('.inp_name').on('change', function() {
    $('.original-output .name_text').text($(this).val());
  });
})();

// Your js
(function() {
  var version = 0;
  $('.inp_name').on('change', function() {
    version++;
    // Don't use clone as your events starts working in cloned code also which you don't expect
    //$('.original-output').clone().appendTo('.copied-output');
    $('.copied-output').append($('.original-output').html());
    $('.copied-output').append(`<div>Version: ${version}</div>`);
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Note: Focus out see text getting change.
<div class="original-form">
  Enter text here: <input type="text" class="inp_name" placeholder="enter your name" />
</div>
<div class="original-output">
  Entered name: <span class="name_text">Entered Name</span>
</div>

<div class="copied-output">
</div>
```